# Get phone orientation from the rotation vector in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, geometry

I believe this should be a common problem but I searched all over the internet but cannot find a proper tutorial.

I get the rotation vector of the phone from the Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR, whose I've fully understood after some study in rotation vector from WikiPedia.

But I'm having difficulty to convert it into the angles of rotations (the pitch, roll, and azimuth value). Is there any reference I can refer to? or how should I do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: From a very quick read of the official document, I think you would call getRotationMatrixFromVector() and then getOrientation(). If you want the azimuth to represent the direction of the back camera then you have to call remapCoordinateSystems() before getOrientation().

Comment: I use TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD extensively and if you do it right, it works very well. I never even look at TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR because it requires a gyro and not all devices have it. Did you do any coding yet, if so is the result stable?

Comment: @HoanNguyen The result is quite stable from what I see... I think can be used for quick-testing purpose at least ;)

Comment: Good, you should try to understand Rotation matrix from a linear algebra point of view (that is Rotation matrix is an orthogonal change of basis matrix). It will make your life much easier when trying to figure out what you have to do with the device orientation, position etc...